# Concatenate two numerical values to make a new column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two columns in my dataframe.

```
var1    var2
01       001
```

I would like to create a third column that joins them together:

```
var1    var2    var3
01       001    01001
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use simple concatenate by `+` with casting by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['var3'] = df.var1.astype(str) + df.var2.astype(str)
print df
  var1 var2   var3
0   01  001  01001
```

If `type` of both columns is `string` casting is omited:

```
print type(df.loc[0,'var1'])
<type 'str'>
print type(df.loc[0,'var2'])
<type 'str'>

df['var3'] = df.var1 + df.var2
print df
  var1 var2   var3
0   01  001  01001
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to both columns to string and then join both the columns to form the third column.

Code:

```
df['var1']=df['var1'].astype(str)
df['var2']=df['var2'].astype(str)
df['var3'] = df[['var1', 'var2']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one-liner:

```
df['var3'] = df[['var1', 'var2']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```